# Facing issue with running job from crontab

Tags: shell-script, shell, cron

I scheduled a shell script in crontab it's not running when i tried manually trigger the same command which i used in crontab i am seeing below error

```
nohup ./home/rahul/data_script/data_backup_scripts/data_backup.sh /home/rahul/data_script/data_backup_scripts/data.param > /home/rahul/data_script/data_backup_scripts/log/nohup.$(date --iso).out
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
nohup: failed to run command ‘./home/rahul/data_script/data_backup_scripts/database_backup.sh’: No such file or directory
```

But i have another job which i scheduled through crontab which is running successfully and i am triggering the job as below

```
nohup sh /home/rahul/ddl_script/ddl_backup/ddl_backup.sh /home/rahul/ddl_script/ddl_scripts/data.param > /home/rahul/ddl_script/ddl_scripts/log/nohup.$(date --iso).out
```

Please help me what the problem in this when i am doing the ls on this location i can see the script located in this location and i have 777 permission over the folder and sub folders also

```
/home/rahul/data_script/data_backup_scripts/database_backup.sh
```

Comment: ./home is not the same as /home

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should remove the dot from ./home

```
/home/rahul/data_script/data_backup_scripts/data_backup.sh
```

The dot is used to refer your actual folder but when you execute something with full path you don't need it unless you have a subhome folder structure under your actual folder.

About the redirection, I recommend you to create a script that calls and executes your actual sentence. I did redirection inside the cron but it's difficult to trace and test. So create a script which encapsules your functionality and test it alone, then call it from the cron.

Finally, about the use of nohup you don't need it in cron, because it's being execute by a service so it can't be logged out during the execution.

Answer (score 0):

The dot in front of the /home is wrong. Delete it.

Since I was corrected about the redirections, I would still think about using an intermediate script, for this purpose of a more brief crontab file, where you have more flexibility to manage the logging, for example filtering it.

Comment: Redirections work in crontab.

Comment: @Kusalananda: OK, I take your word for granted.

Answer (score 0):

The nohup command should be

```
nohup /home/rahul/data_script/data_backup_scripts/data_backup.sh /home/rahul/data_script/data_backup_scripts/data.param > /home/rahul/data_script/data_backup_scripts/log/nohup.$(date --iso).out &
```

The dot "." had as effect that you needed to  be in root, "/", to run it succesfully.  Also, nohup has not much sense unless you run the command in background, therefore the "&" at the end.